# Tiny MIDI sequencer for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, window, midi

Looking for MIDI software, which I can use to play music using my USB MIDI keyboard. The problem is that I have Asus EEEPC and it's not that powerful, so the software need to be as tiny as possible.

Comment: Cakewalk, which is too slow

Comment: define "too slow".  Do you mean it takes too long between when you hit the key, and when you hear the sound?  Is that what you mean by "too slow"?  What make and model USB Midi Keyboard do you have?  Did it come with software?  Is there software for it at the manufacturer's website that will allow you to play music with it?  More information please.

Comment: exactly, the lag is too big between I press key and I hear it. The software which comes with kbd manufacturer is also huge. The model of kbd is M-AUDIO.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is not with Cakewalk.  The software is not "too slow".  The software is not too huge.  This has nothing to do with the size of the installation, or the fact that you are using it on a netbook, etc.

Your issue is with LATENCY.  You will have this problem regardless of what sequencer program you use, because it is a hardware and driver issue.

You need to install Zero Latency drivers.  Like, [ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.com/).  You install them, and then you choose that for the output in the Cakewalk settings, rather than your current audio drivers.  Then, you will hear what you hit, when you hit it.

Answer (score 1):

While @Bon Gart is pretty much right, I would recommend checking out [Reaper](http://reaper.fm) if you are looking for a minimal MIDI host just for playing around with some synths.

Comment: everything I can find in the Reaper Forum regarding latency (the delay the OP talks about) still points to needing to install something like ASIO4ALL to replace any native hardware drivers.  So, using Reaper wouldn't solve this individual's issue.